# geo_point mapping python and StreamSets fails with Elasticsearch

Tags: python, json, elasticsearch, streamsets

I have this mapping in elasticsearch

```
"mappings": {
          "properties": {
                "fromCoordinates": {"type": "geo_point"},
                "toCoordinates": {"type": "geo_point"},
                "seenCoordinates": {"type": "geo_point"},
            }
        }
```

With the kibana's console, there is no problem with all possible combinations of geo_ip [fields supported by elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/geo-point.html), i.e:

(lat, lon)

```
PUT /anindex/_doc/1
{
   "fromCoordinates": {
     "lat": 36.857200622558594    
     "lon": 117.21600341796875,

  },
  "toCoordinates": {
    "lat": 22.639299392700195    
    "lon": 113.81099700927734,

  },
  "seenCoordinates": {
     "lat": 36.91663    
     "lon": 117.216,
   }
}
```

(lon,lat)

```
PUT /anindex/_doc/2
{
 "fromCoordinates": [36.857200622558594, 117.21600341796875], 
 "toCoordinates": [22.639299392700195, 113.81099700927734], 
 "seenCoordinates": [36.91663, 117.216] 
}
```

But a I tried inserting, into elasticsearch, the data through python, and I always have this error:

```
RequestError(400, 'illegal_argument_exception', 'mapper [fromCoordinates] of different type, current_type [geo_point], merged_type [ObjectMapper]')
```

In python, I construct the json from a dictionary, and this is the result when I printed:

```
fromCoordinates = {}
fromCoordinates['lat'] = fromLat  
fromCoordinates['lon'] = fromLon 

dataDictionary.update({'fromCoordinates': fromCoordinates , 'toCoordinates': toCoordinates, 'seenCoordinates': seenCoordinates})
```

```
print(json.dumps(dataDictionary).encode('utf-8'))
```

```
{"fromCoordinates": {"lat": 43.9962005615, "lon": 125.684997559}, 
"toCoordinates": {"lat": 40.080101013183594, "lon": 116.58499908447266}, 
"seenCoordinates": {"lat": 33.62672, "lon": 109.37243}}
```

and load with this

```
data = json.dumps(dataDictionary).encode('utf-8')
es.create(index='anindex', doc_type='document', id=0, body=data)
```

The array version has the same problems:

```
fromCoordinates = [fromLon, fromLat]
```

This is the json created and printed in python:

```
{"fromCoordinates": [113.81099700927734, 22.639299392700195], 
  "toCoordinates": [106.8010025024414, 26.53849983215332], 
   "seenCoordinates": [107.46743, 26.34169]}
```

In this case I have this response

```
RequestError: RequestError(400, 'mapper_parsing_exception', 'geo_point expected')
```

The same error occurs if I try with StreamSets to elasticsearch, having the both types of json shown before:

```
mapper [fromCoordinates] of different type, current_type [geo_point], merged_type [ObjectMapper]
```

Any ideas?

**UPDATE:**

```
GET /anindex/_mapping
```

```
{ "anindex" : 
   { "mappings" : 
     { "properties" : 
       { "fromCoordinates" : 
          { "type" : "geo_point" }, 
        "toCoordinates" : 
           { "type" : "geo_point" }, 
        "seenCoordinates" : { "type" : "geo_point" } 
       }
      }
    }
 }
```

**SOLUTION:**

After the example given by @jzzfs I realized that the doc_type parameter in `es.create(index='anindex', doc_type='document', id=0, body=data)`, is causing the error, I removed it, and it worked..... But I still wondering why in StreamSets has the same error... but I`ll continue with python.

Comment: could you please share your fromCoordinates field mapping? GET anindex/_mapping

Comment: ```{
  "anindex" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "fromCoordinates" : {
          "type" : "geo_point"
        },
        "toCoordinates" : {
          "type" : "geo_point"
        },        
        "seenCoordinates" : {
          "type" : "geo_point"
        }
       }
      }
    }
 }```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were using an older version of elasticsearch  (e.g. 6.1) and upgraded to a newer version (e.g. 7.X) - you need to remove doc_type on your indexing pattern as newer version do not accept this object anymore.

old indexing pattern

```
res=es_local.index(index='local-index',doc_type='resource', body=open_doc,id=_id,request_timeout=60)
```

new indexing pattern

```
res=es_local.index(index='local-index', body=open_doc,id=_id,request_timeout=60)
```

Note:- no doc_type in new indexing pattern (assumes indexing using python).

Comment: Thanks, that was the mistake I found thanks to @jzzfs Thanks anyway for your help too. I had legacy code, but I have a fresh 7.6 elastic running.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you first had the `object` mapping on `fromCoordinates` and then tried to update the mapping. Try dropping & recreating the index and then all these variants should work fine:

---

Python

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
import time

es_instance = Elasticsearch(['http://localhost:9200'])

es_instance.indices.create(
    'anindex',
    body={"mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "fromCoordinates": {"type": "geo_point"},
            "toCoordinates": {"type": "geo_point"},
            "seenCoordinates": {"type": "geo_point"}
        }
    }})

es_instance.create(
    index="anindex",
    id=0,
    body={
        "fromCoordinates": {"lat": 43.9962005615, "lon": 125.684997559},
        "toCoordinates": {"lat": 40.080101013183594, "lon": 116.58499908447266},
        "seenCoordinates": {"lat": 33.62672, "lon": 109.37243}})

es_instance.create(
    index="anindex",
    id=1,
    body={
        "fromCoordinates": [
            117.21600341796875,
            36.857200622558594
        ],
        "toCoordinates": [
            113.81099700927734,
            22.639299392700195
        ],
        "seenCoordinates": [
            117.216,
            36.91663
        ]
    })

# syncing is not instant so wait
time.sleep(1)

print(es_instance.count(index="anindex"))
```

---

Kibana:

```
DELETE anindex

PUT anindex
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "fromCoordinates": {
        "type": "geo_point"
      },
      "toCoordinates": {
        "type": "geo_point"
      },
      "seenCoordinates": {
        "type": "geo_point"
      }
    }
  }
}

PUT /anindex/_doc/1
{
  "fromCoordinates": {
    "lat": 36.857200622558594,
    "lon": 117.21600341796875
  },
  "toCoordinates": {
    "lat": 22.639299392700195,
    "lon": 113.81099700927734
  },
  "seenCoordinates": {
    "lat": 36.91663,
    "lon": 117.216
  }
}

PUT /anindex/_doc/2
{
  "fromCoordinates": [
    117.21600341796875,
    36.857200622558594
  ],
  "toCoordinates": [
    113.81099700927734,
    22.639299392700195
  ],
  "seenCoordinates": [
    117.216,
    36.91663
  ]
}

PUT anindex/_doc/3
{
  "fromCoordinates": "22.639299392700195,113.81099700927734",
  "toCoordinates": "26.53849983215332,106.8010025024414",
  "seenCoordinates": "26.34169,107.46743"
}
```

Comment: Thanks @jzzfs for your quick response. With curl, postman, kibana's console there is no problem with that. It clearly seems that the nested fields are treated as an object and not pure json when I send from python or from StreamsSets. I also tested with python and StreamSets without nested fields, and everything is ok. I also tried, without creating the mapping first and leaving elastic to guess and create by itself, and mapped the coordinates as numbers or strings.

Comment: If you let it guess, in this case it'll not map `geo_point`s correctly by itself. So set the mapping first and only then proceed to syncing. What do you mean by "pure json"?

Comment: I mean plain-json. I also put it in the python code as plain, built "by hand", not from dictionary, and got the same error.

Comment: It worked! The issue was...... the doc_type parameter in es.create(index='anindex', doc_type='document', id=0, body=data), removed it, and it worked..... thanks a lot for your time!  But I still wondering why in StreamSets get the same error... but I`ll continue with python.